# How Can i build Data Driven framework with Watir Webdriver where test data will be excel files

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I need help to build data driven framework for `WATIR Webdriver`. Here my concern is: Can we build data driven framework by reading data from excel in `Watir-webdriver` as we have option in `Selenium+Testng` framework

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you need a webdriver to read in an excel file? There are plenty of ruby gems out there that can handle .xls and .xlsx files.

Comment: @Jeff Price : Can you please suggest me the sample gems to handle it , i am new to it

Comment: There are a ton out there. Search for ruby excel spreadsheet  and you'll find a lot. 
https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet and https://github.com/pythonicrubyist/creek are just two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at the Ruby `CSV` library. CSV stands for `comma separated values` and can be used to read data from Excel spreadsheets. To use this library, simply use `require csv` in your script.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html